# Quebra de linha ao digitar entradas

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Tenho um vetor de structs com 10 pessoas e desejo que minha função de cadastro receba somente uma pessoa por vez. 
No terminal, o cadastro da primeira pessoa é feito **corretamente** mas depois obtenho essa "quebra" de linha, pula sozinho do nome que iria digitar para a idade. Por que isso ocorre?

```
[danielamorais@localhost Desktop]$ ./ex3
Digite o nome:
Daniela
Digite a idade:
18
Digite o nome:
Digite a idade:
```

Código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define TAM 10

typedef struct{
char nome[30];
int idade;
} Pessoa;

void cadastrarPessoa(Pessoa *pessoa){
        puts("Digite o nome:");
        gets((*pessoa).nome);
        puts("Digite a idade:");
        scanf("%d", &((*pessoa).idade));
}

void lerPessoas(Pessoa *p){
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        cadastrarPessoa(&p[i]);
    }
}

void imprimirVetor(Pessoa *p){
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf("Nome: %s", p[i].nome);
        printf("Idade: %d", p[i].idade);
    }
}

void main(){
    Pessoa *pessoa = (Pessoa *)malloc(sizeof(Pessoa) * TAM);
    lerPessoas(pessoa);
    imprimirVetor(pessoa);
}
```

Comment: Vc esta no linux ou windows?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Fedora 23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para corrigir o problema de pular linha é necessário limpar o buffer do teclado com o `__fpurge` que é deixado pelo `scanf`, veja como ficou as modificações:

```
void cadastrarPessoa(Pessoa *pessoa){
        puts("Digite o nome:");
        gets((*pessoa).nome);
        puts("Digite a idade:");
        scanf("%d", &((*pessoa).idade));
        __fpurge(stdin);/*<-------Mudei aqui*/
}
```

Tembem é necessario declarar a biblioteca `stdio_ext.h` para usar o `__fpurge`, sugiro trocar o `gets` pelo `fgets`, porque o `gets` e vulneravel ao bufferoverflow.

O `i` não se declara dentro do `for`, tem que ficar fora, veja:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){faz algo....}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada! E quanto a declaração do i, isso não varia de acordo com o compilador? Alguns compilam normalmente e outros não.

Comment: O gcc não aceita, acho que somente o g++ que é do c++ que permite declaração de variáveis dentro do for e do while.